# Best way to iterate two lists and extract few things?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have two classes as shown below. I need to use these two classes to extract few things.

```
public final class ProcessMetadata {
  private final String clientId;
  private final String deviceId;
  // .. lot of other fields here

  // getters here
}

public final class ProcMetadata {
  private final String deviceId;
  private final Schema schema;
  // .. lot of other fields here
}
```

Now I have below code where I am iterating above two classes and extracting `schema` given a `clientId`.

```
public Optional<Schema> getSchema(final String clientId) {
  for (ProcessMetadata metadata1 : processMetadataList) {
    if (metadata1.getClientId().equalsIgnoreCase(clientId)) {
      String deviceId = metadata1.getDeviceId();
      for (ProcMetadata metadata2 : procMetadataList) {
        if (metadata2.getDeviceId().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceId)) {
          return Optional.of(metadata2.getSchema());
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return Optional.absent();
}
```

Is there any better way of getting what I need by iterating those two above classes in couple of lines instead of what I have? I am using Java 7.

Comment: you are using Optional in java7 ?

Comment: yes it is from guava not java 8 one :)

Comment: do you have Streams, too?

Comment: That I don't know. I doubt it is part of Java 7.

Comment: do you need to nest the 2 loops? isn't `clientId` unique?

Comment: but how will I get `schema` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing a [quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)* search operation, which is inneficient. You can do this operation in constant time by first creating (in linear time) a [mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) from id->object for each list. This would look something like this:

```
// do this once, in the constructor or wherever you create these lists
// even better discard the lists and use the mappings everywhere
Map<String, ProcessMetadata> processMetadataByClientId = new HashMap<>();
for (ProcessMetadata process : processMetadataList) {
  processMetadataByClientId.put(process.getClientId(), process);
}

Map<String, ProcMetadata> procMetadataByDeviceId = new HashMap<>();
for (ProcMetadata metadata2 : procMetadataList) {
  procMetadataByDeviceId.put(proc.getDeviceId(), proc);
}
```

Then your lookup simply becomes:

```
public Optional<Schema> getSchema(String clientId) {
  ProcessMetadata process = processMetadataByClientId.get(clientId);
  if (process != null) {
    ProcMetadata proc = procMetadataByDeviceId.get(process.getDeviceId());
    if (proc != null) {
      return Optional.of(proc.getSchema());
    }
  }
  return Optional.absent();
}
```

In Java 8 you could write it like this:

```
public Optional<Schema> getSchema(String clientId) {
 return Optional.fromNullable(processMetadataByClientId.get(clientId))
     .map(p -> procMetadataByDeviceId.get(p.getDeviceId()))
     .map(p -> p.getSchema());
}
```

---

* In practice your algorithm is linear assuming client IDs are unique, but it's still technically O(n^2) because you potentially touch every element of the proc list for every element of the process list. A slight tweak to your algorithm can guarentee linear time (again assuming unique IDs):

```
public Optional<Schema> getSchema(final String clientId) {
  for (ProcessMetadata metadata1 : processMetadataList) {
    if (metadata1.getClientId().equalsIgnoreCase(clientId)) {
      String deviceId = metadata1.getDeviceId();
      for (ProcMetadata metadata2 : procMetadataList) {
        if (metadata2.getDeviceId().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceId)) {
          return Optional.of(metadata2.getSchema());
        }
      }
      // adding a break here ensures the search doesn't become quadratic
      break;
    }
  }
  return Optional.absent();
}
```

Though of course using maps ensures constant-time, which is far better.

Comment: Did you mean `processMetadataByClientId.put(process.getClientId(), process);`?

Answer (score 1):

I wondered what could be done with Guava, and accidentally wrote this hot mess.

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.tryFind

public Optional<Schema> getSchema(final String clientId) {
  Optional<String> deviceId = findDeviceIdByClientId(clientId);
  return deviceId.isPresent() ? findSchemaByDeviceId(deviceId.get()) : Optional.absent();
}

public Optional<String> findDeviceIdByClientId(String clientId) {
  return tryFind(processMetadataList, new ClientIdPredicate(clientId))
    .transform(new Function<ProcessMetadata, String>() {
      String apply(ProcessMetadata processMetadata) {
        return processMetadata.getDeviceId();
      }
    });
}

public Optional<Schema> findSchemaByDeviceId(String deviceId) {
  return tryFind(procMetadataList, new DeviceIdPredicate(deviceId.get())
    .transform(new Function<ProcMetadata, Schema>() {
      Schema apply(ProcMetadata procMetadata) {
        return processMetadata.getSchema();
      }
    });
}

class DeviceIdPredicate implements Predicate<ProcMetadata> {
  private String deviceId;

  public DeviceIdPredicate(String deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean apply(ProcMetadata metadata2) {
    return metadata2.getDeviceId().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceId)
  }
}

class ClientIdPredicate implements Predicate<ProcessMetadata> {
  private String clientId;

  public ClientIdPredicate(String clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean apply(ProcessMetadata metadata1) {
    return metadata1.getClientId().equalsIgnoreCase(clientId);
  }
}
```

Sorry.

Comment: I just had to give you a vote for being brave enough to admit what you did ;-)